# Error when exporting UV map with Python

Tags: python, uv

I'm fiddling around with the Python API, and I face an issue that I can't understand. I'm trying to export as a PNG an UV map when I execute my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Programmes\Blender\2.78\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 187, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo)
TypeError: Calling operator "bpy.ops.uv.export_layout" error, expected a string enum in ('INVOKE_DEFAULT', 'INVOKE_REGION_WIN', 'INVOKE_REGION_CHANNELS', 'INVOKE_REGION_PREVIEW', 'INVOKE_AREA', 'INVOKE_SCREEN', 'EXEC_DEFAULT', 'EXEC_REGION_WIN', 'EXEC_REGION_CHANNELS', 'EXEC_REGION_PREVIEW', 'EXEC_AREA', 'EXEC_SCREEN')
```

And here is my code:

```
bpy.ops.script.python_file_run(filepath="D:\\Programmes\\Blender\\2.78\\scripts\\presets\\units_length\\centimeters.py")
bpy.context.active_object.dimensions.x = object_dimensions[0]
bpy.context.active_object.dimensions.y = object_dimensions[1]
bpy.context.active_object.dimensions.z = object_dimensions[2]

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(offset=offset, vertex_only=False)
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()
uv_path = os.path.join(save_path, 'uv_{}.png'.format(object_name))
bpy.ops.uv.export_layout(uv_path, mode='PNG', size=(2048, 2048), opacity=1.0)
```

Do you have any idea of what I did wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the actual intention of the script to your question.

Comment: more context is needed, e.g. contents of centimeters.py

Comment: All operator parameters need to be passed as keyword arguments,  `bpy.ops.uv.export_layout(filepath=uv_path)`  Otherwise if unnamed it expects an enum eg 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' or a context dictionary. [Explained here](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.html#calling-operators)